# Why is the Transcendence degree of a point in $K^n$ equal to $0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Suppose $(x_1,...,x_n)\in K^n$ where $K$ is a field. Then we know that $\{(x_1,...,x_n)\}=Z(X_1-x_1,...X_n-x_n)$ i.e $\{(x_1,...,x_n)\}$ is a algebraic set (and variety). I want to show that the field of fractions of $K[X_1,...,X_n]/I(\{(x_1,...,x_n)\})$ has transcendence degree of $0$ over $K$. Does anyone know how to proceed. I think $I(\{(x_1,...,x_n)\})=(X_1-x_1,...X_n-x_n)$ but I do not know what $K[X_1,...,X_n]/(X_1-x_1,...X_n-x_n)$ is. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u:P\in K[X_1,\ldots, X_n]\mapsto P(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in K$.

Then $\ker(u)=I(\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\})$ and $u$ is obviously surjective. Then, first isomorphism theorem yields that your quotient is isomorphic to $K$, which has transcendence degree $0$ over $K$.

Moreover, you are right about $I(\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\})$, that I will denote $I$ for short. It is indeed $(X_1-x_1,\ldots, X_n-x_n)$.

Set $J=(X_1-x_1,\ldots, X_n-x_n)$, and note that $J\subset I$

To see that $I=J$ , note that $X_i=(X_i-x_i)+x_i$, so $X_i$ is congruent to a constant polynomial modulo  $J$. It follows that any polynomial $P$ is congruent to a constant modulo $J$, that is $P=c+Q,$ for some $Q\in J$.

Evaluation at $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ yields, using the fact that $J\subset I$ that $c=P(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. Hence $P(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0\iff P\in J$, that is $\ker(u)=J$, meaning $I=J$.